# Error when copying images in python notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error, shutil

I'm trying to copy images from one file to another in my ipynb and I'm getting a IsADirectoryError.

```
import os 
import shutil

f = sorted(os.listdir('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/noshot/'))
f1 = sorted(os.listdir('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/goodshot/'))
f2 = sorted(os.listdir('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/badshot/'))



orders = range(0,800)


for o in orders:
    fi = f[o]
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/noshot/', fi), os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/training/', fi))
    
for o in orders:
    fi = f1[o]
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/goodshot/', fi), os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/training/', fi))
    
for o in orders:
    fi = f2[o]
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/badshot/', fi), os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/training/', fi))
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNZA1.png)
[I have more than 800 images in each of the files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeGFL.png)

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` returns both files and directories but `shutil.copyfile` accepts only files

you can avoid passing directories into `shutil.copyfile` by filtering them out using `os.path.isfile`

to prevent index out of range you can check if o is greater then the lenght of f (f1, f2) and break out of the for loop if this is the case

```
    import os 
    import shutil
    
    f = sorted(os.listdir('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/noshot/'))
    f1 = sorted(os.listdir('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/goodshot/'))
    f2 = sorted(os.listdir('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/badshot/'))

    #fix
    f = [i for i in f if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/noshot/', i)]
    f1 = [i for i in f1 os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/goodshot/', i)]
    f2 = [i for i in f2 if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/badshot/', i)]
    
    
    orders = range(0,800)
    
    
    for o in orders:
        if o >= len(f):
            break
        fi = f[o]
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/noshot/', fi), os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/training/', fi))
        
    for o in orders:
        if o >= len(f1):
            break
        fi = f1[o]
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/goodshot/', fi), os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/training/', fi))
        
    for o in orders:
        if o >= len(f2):
            break
        fi = f2[o]
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/badshot/', fi), os.path.join('/home/jovyan/work/training/', fi))
```

Comment: Hi, it's showing list index out of range at fi = f[o]. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njgtD.png)

Comment: Hi, None of the images are copied. This is because os.path.isfile(i) is returning false for all images , so len(f) = len(f1) = len(f2) = 0. As a result, all the for loops are breaking out without copying any file.

Comment: It still doesn't work. As mentioned above , the problem is with os.path.isfile(i) , it's returning false so none of the files are getting copied to f , f1 and f2.

Comment: @akshit.C I think the issue was that i was only the file name and not the full path; i fixed this

Comment: It's not throwing any errors , but it is copying only 845 files of the required 2400.

Comment: @akshit.C could you print out the lenght of f, f1 and f2 after all directories have been removed

Comment: There is no problem with the lengths of f , f1 and f2 , all the file names are added properly. I think something is going wrong while copying.[Length of f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWNt7.png)

Comment: @akshit.C try using `shutil.copy2` instead of  `shutil.copyfile`

Answer (score 0):

```
    import shutil
    import os
    import glob

    paths = ['/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/noshot/',
             '/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/goodshot/',
             '/home/jovyan/work/shot/shot/badshot/']
    
    dst = '/home/jovyan/work/training/'
    
    for path in paths:
        x = 0
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.*')):
            if x < 800:
                shutil.copy2(file, dst)
            x += 1
```

Comment: For some reason, [it's copying the entire ipynb and its previous checkpoint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVbnr.png)

Comment: @akshit.C Does it copy the images too or just the ippynb?

Comment: Just the ipynb.

Comment: @akshit.C i modified this solution to use `os.listdir` instead of `os.walk` and still get all subfolders

Comment: It's able to copy 1022 images out of the 2400 required.

Comment: @akshit.C i replaced `os.listdir` with `glob.glob`